# findFragmentByTag() returns null only on the third tab of the ActioBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

I am using a tabbed `Activity` provided by Android with `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener`,`ViewPager` and `FragmentPagerAdapter`. The parent `Activty` cointains and manages three `Fragment`. In addition, the parent Activity has a method to save the data provided by the fragments. In order to get the data defined in them (and not sended by the parent Activity) I am wrote the following code:

`MyFragment frag = (MyFragment) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getActiveFragment(mViewPager,1,getSupportFragmentManager());`

Where `getActiveFragment()` is

```
        public Fragment getActiveFragment(ViewPager container, int position, FragmentManager mFragmentManager) {
            String name = makeFragmentName(container.getId(), position);
            return  mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
        }


        private String makeFragmentName(int viewId, int index) {
            return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + index;
        }
```

Actually, I have the following problem: when I try to save data provided by the three fragment, I have a `java.lang.NullPointerException` caused by the third fragment which is null. This happens only if I do not display on my device the second or third fragment.
I do not understand how to avoid and fix this behaviour.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the third fragment not being created if only the first tab/fragment is shown. 
The ViewPager per default internally prepares the visible fragment, the one left to it and the one right to it. 
Try

[viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29)